# Uploading Images To A Common Google Drive Account Using Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I am trying to find a way to upload images to one particular account in google drive from my flutter app. Please see the below flowchart for reference.

User 1 -> Selects Image From Device -> Show that image in flutter app -> Upload In test@gmail.com Google Drive -> Enable sharing to everyone who has the link -> Get link in flutter app.

Do note that the user 1 does not have access to test@gmail.com

Comment: I would like to help you but I am kind of confused... How can you upload images to `test@gmail.com` when you do not have access/credentials to `test@gmail.com`? You have to authenticate first... Well... If you are just asking how to upload images to Google Drive, that is easy. Please clarify.

Comment: Have you considered using service accounts?

Comment: @minchaej What I am thinking of doing is instead of using Firebase Storage, I wanted to use google drive as a backend for all the images. So like if a user puts up his profile picture I want it to store in my google drive account instead of firebase storage. Something like that. Hope this made it clear. Please let me know if any other clarifications are required.

Comment: @LakshyaJain i already implement that flow, but i got some issue, if i access images from google drive in one time, just say load  20 images and show in listview, that will be get response Error 403, couse google drive is limited for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can upload images to Google Drive.

You can upload the image and download the image using `Google Drive API`.

Here is the manual:

- [How to upload files to Google Drive?](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [How to download files to Google Drive?](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Let me know if you have more questions.

**PS**: However, it is **NOT** encouraged to use Google Drive as your `CDN` because Google Drive will limit your API usage when your traffic is quite large. If you plan on scaling your app in the future, I would recommend a proper `CDN`.

Comment: If I am planning to use google drive just to load some default assets in my flutter app, would you be recommending to do that. Just like a few asset images.

Comment: Quite a large number actually since in the beginning its going to be just 1 whole country and later on expanding. Like what I am planning is since its just some assets which are rarely going to be changed so I will upload the images in my google drive manually and create a share link in the format flutter accepts and display that. So that's the use case I meant by having some default assets in the network.

Comment: Ok... then... NEVER use Google Drive as your CDN. No matter how few, how static, how small the image is, if your user base is quite large, it will not meet your needs. In addition, if you are considering expanding your app, Google Drive has no scalability. Please use a proper CDN. I am saying this from my honest industry experience.

Comment: Alright @minchaej
Thanks a lot for your help. Would you suggest some good CDN's that work well with firebase.

Comment: @LakshyaJain Sure, without any doubt, I would recommend `Amazon CloudFront`. It is an industry-leading CDN, very flexible and scalable. It integrates very well with pretty much everything, including Firebase.

Comment: Sure, no problem.